# How to pass an event Type to a widget with block pattern?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create an app with block pattern and `flutter_block` library. It is working, but now I want to reduce the code.

I have a lot of:

#### dart

```
Padding(
  padding:
      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
  child: TextField(
    inputFormatters: [
      BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"))
    ],
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'label text'),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: _service,
    onChanged: (value) =>
        {_prefsBloc.dispatch(SetServicePrefs(value))},
  ),
),
```

I'm transforming that in a widget:

#### dart

```
class SettingTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String labelText;


  SettingTextField({this.text, this.labelText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PrefsBloc _prefsBloc = BlocProvider.of<PrefsBloc>(context);
    final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
    _controller.text = this.text;

    if (this.text != null) {
      _controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: this.text.length);
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
      child: TextField(
          inputFormatters: [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"))],
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: this.labelText),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: _controller,
          onChanged: (value) {}
            
    );
  }
}
```

For each field, I have a different event to dispatch to block like:

```
_prefsBloc.dispatch(SetServicePrefs(value))
```

But I really don't know how to pass the type `SetServicePrefs` to my widget and use it in the `onChanged` function.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional callback field to SettingTextField:

```
class SettingTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String labelText;    
  final Function(PrefsBloc bloc, value) onChanged;

    ...

    TextField(
              inputFormatters: [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"))],
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: this.labelText),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: _controller,
              onChanged: (value) => onChanged(_prefsBloc, value)
        )

...

}
```

Then call SettingTextField:

```
SettingTextField(
...
onChanged: (bloc, value) => bloc.dispatch(SomeEventType(value))
...
)
```